# How to make HTML Text unselectable

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, highlighting, textselection

I would like to add text to my webpage as a label and make it unselectable.

In other words, When the mouse cursor is over the text I would like it to not turn into a text selecting cursor at all.

A good example of what I'm trying to achieve is the buttons on this website (Questions,Tags,Users,...)

Answer (score 381, accepted):

You can't do this with plain vanilla HTML, so JSF can't do much for you here as well.

If you're targeting [decent browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=user-select-none) only, then just make use of CSS3:

```css
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="unselectable">Unselectable label</label>
```

If you'd like to cover older browsers as well, then consider this JavaScript fallback:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2310734</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
                for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    disableSelection(labels[i]);
                }
            };
            function disableSelection(element) {
                if (typeof element.onselectstart != 'undefined') {
                    element.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
                } else if (typeof element.style.MozUserSelect != 'undefined') {
                    element.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
                } else {
                    element.onmousedown = function() { return false; };
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Try to select this</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're already using [jQuery](http://jquery.com), then here's another example which adds a new function `disableSelection()` to jQuery so that you can use it anywhere in your jQuery code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 2310734 with jQuery</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.fn.extend({ 
                disableSelection: function() { 
                    this.each(function() { 
                        if (typeof this.onselectstart != 'undefined') {
                            this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
                        } else if (typeof this.style.MozUserSelect != 'undefined') {
                            this.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
                        } else {
                            this.onmousedown = function() { return false; };
                        }
                    }); 
                } 
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('label').disableSelection();            
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Try to select this</label>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer has a problem, and it does not work in all cases any more. Other browsers use their own vendor prefixes, and you are using `MozUserSelect` only. New browsers will use no prefix. Look at the list of all possible javascript prefixes: ['Moz', 'Webkit', 'ms', 'O', 'Khtml', ''] /*with empty string for no prefix*/. You should correctly deal with camelCase. And it's a serious bug that you are overwriting `onselectstart` and `onmousedown` event handlers with your function, so previously attached handlers do not work any more. I can Update your code if you like

Comment: @BalusC as far as I see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select, you still can't do this cross browser with CSS only (old IE, Opera and Firefox). So a good hybrid solution is needed

Comment: And @Blowsie has reported problems in comments.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/user-select-none

Comment: If you do end up adding the disableSelection to jQuery - I did, and it works great, but give it another name. In case you end up using jQuery UI there's a name conflict when using plugins like resizable. Just a heads up.

Comment: try like this - `*.unselectable { ... }`

Comment: That's why I love being a developer, now I found how to copy some piece of text they don't want me to copy. Just search for the problem they probably had :).

Comment: I want to know how one would undo the jquery function. Like `$(".element").mousedown(function() { $('body').disableSelection(); )}; $(window).mouseup(function() { $('body').undoThedisableSelectionFunction(); });`

Comment: You or someone here might do an easy job of answering this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70930570/how-to-make-whole-document-selectable-after-making-it-unselectable

Answer (score 185):

No one here posted an answer with all of the correct CSS variations, so here it is:

```css
.not-selectable {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="not-selectable">Not-selectable text</p>
```

Comment: These do work well in modern browsers, but be aware that older ones like IE7 will not support this.

Comment: In Chrome 18, this is only a visual effect, the text is still selectable.

Comment: Can still select text in Opera 11

Comment: Can still select text in Opera.

Comment: For Opera, does the '-o-' prefix work?

Comment: @joeytwiddle Might be worth sticking it in just in case.

Comment: CSS does not work in Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).  Still copies to clipboard...

Comment: @RonRoyston the questions is about selecting not copying. But maybe u want [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6ppm9jt5/1/).

Answer (score 63):

The full modern solution to your problem is purely CSS-based, but note that older browsers won't support it, in which cases you'd need to fallback to solutions such as the others have provided.

So in pure CSS:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

However the mouse cursor will still change to a caret when over the element's text, so you add to that:

```
cursor: default;
```

Modern CSS is pretty elegant.

Comment: you call that modern? having to specify the same thing 6 times?

Comment: yeah I hate the browser prefixes too but oh well they have a history of not agreeing so we got used to having these around.

Comment: @FlavorScape I use [less](http://lesscss.org), so I only have to write this snippet once! :)

Comment: You can also use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide) and specify a _mixin_ for that.

Comment: Specifying the cursor seems to be no longer needed. It will change to `default` automatically with the correct variation of `user-select: none`. Tested in Firefox 61.0.1 and Vivaldi 1.15.1147.47.

Answer (score 12):

I altered the jQuery plugin posted above so it would work on live elements.

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.disableSelection = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        if (typeof this.onselectstart != 'undefined') {
            this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
        } else if (typeof this.style.MozUserSelect != 'undefined') {
            this.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
        } else {
            this.onmousedown = function() { return false; };
        }
    });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Then you could so something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').disableSelection();

    // Or to make everything unselectable
    $('*').disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: This was a great answer, but unfortunately it got outdated. See my comment to @BalusC answer