# Transparent div over text

Tags: css

How do you put a (transparent) image over text to keep it from being selected?
I want my students to type what they see, not just copy/paste.

I'm not worried about them viewing source and copy/pasting from there - if they're that savvy I don't need to worry about them knowing the material.

Comment: Should we guess the mark-up you're using?

Comment: Perhaps you could make the text simply unselectable? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe that this is a great idea, and nor will it work particularly well. Also, without seeing what elements you're using, I'm going to guess, with the following:

```
<p>Something not to copy...<img src="path/to/image.png" /></p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    position: relative;
}

p img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hYmak/2/).

A slightly easier way:

```
p {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hYmak/1/).

A slightly more reliable way (that doesn't rely on updated/'modern' browsers, but which isn't requested in your question, as it uses JavaScript:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i=0, len=paras.length; i<len; i++){
    paras[i].onmousedown = function(){
        return false;
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hYmak/).

Comment: Dang David.  This is a very complete answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, glad to have been of help. =)

Answer (score 0):

Could this be done in a simpler way using z-index? E.g. higher z-index value for the transparent image.

It's an interesting concept you are proposing, though perhaps not 'in the spirit' of website accessibility :-)