# Text selection disable

Tags: jquery, html, css, textselection

I am trying to make text unselectale in div, i am using following code.

```
style="-webkit-touch-callout: none;
       -webkit-user-select: none;
       -khtml-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
       -ms-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;" 
       unselectable="on"
       onselectstart="return false;"
```

this code works perfect, but it does not allow me to click on div content and does not put cursor where i clicked on div content. 
I want to put cursor where i clicked. Div content also have attr `contenteditable="true"`.

Is there any way that i can disable content selection but not mouse click.

Thanks,

Comment: can show me your jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTML Text unselectable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable)

Answer (score 0):

Try check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7vd0or7j/) homie

JS

```
function makeUnselectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        makeUnselectable(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

makeUnselectable(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

Is this you looking for?