# How to select a text with a cursor in a <button> element?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I found a strange behavior, I cannot select a text in a `<button>` element. As an example, please try to select a text in these buttons of Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-buttons

[image]

Is it some standard behavior or is it editable? I need to select text in buttons.

Comment: From my reading `button` with the type of *button* have no default behaviour so this is likely to be browser dependent. Arguably, if the text is to be selectable...a button would not be suitable/appropriate.

Comment: I can select the text just fine. Click outside of the element and drag across.

Comment: @epascarello, yeah, right) But it is not an option in my case

Comment: Well when you drag on a button, it does not select the text...

Answer (score 15):

You could do the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable):
create the following CSS3:

```
.list-group-item{
-webkit-touch-callout: text;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-khtml-user-select: text;
-moz-user-select: text;
-ms-user-select: text;
user-select: text;
}
```

and link the stylesheet. It works on my firefox.

Edit: changed "all" to "text" as Nenad Vracar said. It works in Chrome and Firefox for me now

Comment: No, doesn't work in Chrome,  `47.0.2526.106 m`. Yes, it looks like it is a browser behavior.

Comment: Old comment, but just to confirm, tested and it do work in Mac Chrome 69 and Mac Firefox 6 at least. But it does not work in Safari 12. It do work with `user-select: all` though. But then the user can't choose to only select a single word, everything in that container is selected. 

Answer (score 8):

You can set [`user-select: text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select)

```css
button {
  -webkit-user-select: text;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: text;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: text;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="list-group">
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</button>
  <button type="button" class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/432/)**

Comment: I would suggest this prefix-stack:
`-webkit-user-select: all;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;`

This because Safari doesn't support `user-select: text` on Buttons for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers work in Safari. If the button is just for display and you're ok with it no longer sending `onClick` events, you can use `pointer-events: none` to make it work in Safari.

```css
button {
  -webkit-user-select: text;  /* Chrome */
  -moz-user-select: text;     /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: text;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: text;
  pointer-events: none;       /* Safari */
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can define css property for button like this
For button class add cursor:pointer property.
You can specify either to button directly or to your custom CSS class

cursor : pointer

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question *actually asked*