# Make text not copyable HTML

Tags: css, html

**This is not a duplicate of the question above**

I use `material-icons` on my website. In order to add an icon, you'd have to make something like this:

```
<p class="material-icons">info_outline</p>
```

If I now copy that icon, it would copy the text "info_outline". I know you can make an element unselectable using `user-select: none;` inside you `css`, but there is a problem with that.

Take my snippet for example. If I create an `p` element, with a `span` inside which has `user-select: none;` you won't be able to select (and therefor copy) the span. However, if you copy the whole `p` element, you will still get the contents of the `span`. How can I prevent this from happening?

```css
span {
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p>Copy this text with a <span>unselectable</span> piece of text... Or is it?</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="Past text here">
```

**Edit:**
Since a lot of people say it's a duplicate question to the questions where the answer is `user-select: none;`, just take another look at my question.

I know how user-select works. I know you can make an element unelectable. However, if you select the element around it and copy it's contents, it will copy all it's content, even the element with the `user-select: none;`

Comment: See answer here....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable text selection highlighting using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting-using-css)

Comment: Both of these answers don't cover a element inside another.

Comment: This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ppm9jt5/) works for me in FF52.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in chrome 56.0.2924.87

Comment: But maybe this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ppm9jt5/1/) will help you?

Comment: Mr Lister there is no problem with the selector. He wants to be able to select the content of `p`. And if he makes a copy of the selected text, he don't want to get the content of the `span` inside of `p`.

Comment: Finally someone understands the question. Thank you for being the only one to actually read my question

Comment: You're welcome! :) I can't find a way to get it work in IE. But my second fiddle works in chrome, firefox and opera. Safari should also work.

Comment: Oh, the fiddle does work now for me. IE doesn't work indeed, Edge does work though so that's not a problem. If you make a answer, I'll set is as the answer.

Internet explorer doesn't have to be supported by web developers anymore, right?

Comment: @VellosFree Sorry, but I really didn't read from the question that you did want the p to be selectable, except for the span.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First of all make the element unselectable:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

This already works in Firefox. To get it work in other browsers, you have to work with `pseudo-elements` and `data-attribute`.

Use a `data-attribute` like this:

```
<span data-unselectable="unselectable content"></span>
```

Now we can add this text in the content of our pseudo-element `::before` or `::after`:

```
span::before {
  content: attr(data-unselectable);
}
```

This works because the `dom` will not be updated by the content attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Add css style

```
.youClass {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Or if you want make it better use script some thing like this.

```
<script>
            window.onload = function() {
                var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
                for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                    disableSelection(labels[i]);
                }
            };
            function disableSelection(element) {
                if (typeof element.onselectstart != 'undefined') {
                    element.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
                } else if (typeof element.style.MozUserSelect != 'undefined') {
                    element.style.MozUserSelect = 'none';
                } else {
                    element.onmousedown = function() { return false; };
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: The problem isn't making the element unselectable. The problem is, if I copy the element around it, it shouldn't copy the contents of the unselectable element. Look at my question before answering.