# How to make an input field unselectable

Tags: html, css

How to make this input field unselectable?
I have tried this but i can still select the text:

```css
    input {
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 6px 20px;
      margin: 2px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      outline: none;
    }
    
    input:focus {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      border-color: red;
    }
    
    div.capbg1 {
      user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="capbg1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control2 pull-right" value="<?php echo $capcode2;?>" name="captcha" style="width: 29%;" disabled>
              </div>
```

When i put the text in the div without the input field it works. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: May you are finding this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable

Answer (score 13):

Or, you can use `pointer-events:none`

```css
    input {
      border-radius: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 6px 20px;
      margin: 2px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      outline: none;
      pointer-events:none;
    }
    
    input:focus {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid #555;
      border-color: red;
    }
    
    div.capbg1 {
      user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="capbg1">
                <input type="text" class="form-control2 pull-right" value="<?php echo $capcode2;?>" name="captcha" style="width: 29%;" disabled>
              </div>
```

Comment: Note that you can still tab into the input field.

Comment: This prevents focusing without using tab unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You Can put the `<input.../>` in a `<label>`, then use a pseudo elements `:before or :after` as a transparent layer on your InputBox, then add `user-select: none;` to the `<label>`. Don't forget to set the `z-index`.

```css
    .capbg1 label {
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 6px 20px;
        margin: 2px 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 2px solid #555;

        /* user-select none */
        user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
    }

    .capbg1 label:after {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: tranparent;
        content: "";

        display: block;
        z-index: 999;
    }

    input {
        position: relative;
        outline: none;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    input:focus {
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #555;
        border-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="capbg1">
    <label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control2 pull-right" value="<?php echo $capcode2;?>" name="captcha" disabled>
    </label>
</div>
```