# How to make div and img unselectable

Tags: html, css

I can't make that code unselectable. How can I change it?

I tried placing user-select: none in all of css classes, but it's still selectable.

```
<div class="outer">
    <a href="/">
        <img src="/wp-content/themes/theme/assets/img/logo.png">  
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

user-select is not supported in all browsers without prefix. Try this:

```
.outer {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
}
```

Comment: Strange. It works for me. In what browser? Can you post your complete code, both css and html?

Comment: I made a codepen. Can you select the image? https://codepen.io/bopeterson/pen/oNvbOwa

Answer (score -2):

This was answered here, I can't post it in chat yet, sorry: [How to make HTML Text unselectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310734/how-to-make-html-text-unselectable/2310809#2310809)

Long story short:

```
.outer {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```