# How to prevent users from downloading Presentation ( PPT ) and videos from my HTML page

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

I have an HTML page which resides locally on my machine. I have 2 items on every page 1 - PPT presentation 2 - Video tutorial . I want to prevent users from downloading the content for their personal use. How can this be achieved?

Thanks in Advance !

Maddy

Comment: Too late - they're already downloaded when the page loads for the user.

Comment: This question gets asked once a week.  This is not possible. You can make it a tiny bit harder than right-clicking on a link, but not much. Give up.

Comment: This is not possible as any thing that is displayed in a browser is already downloaded on the client machine. If you don't want it to be downloaded you should not put it on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the short answer is that it cannot not be done in a good way, if the content should be available at your website at the same time.

There are solutions where you obfuscate the path to the file when it is sent to the browser, and then use a JavaScript to "decrypt" the path at the client. But those solutions are in no way bullet proof, as the decryption technique would have to be sent to the client as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one is not easy to do, especially if you show them on your page already. As you do so they'll get downloaded on the browser an there's no way, at least i'm aware of you could do this with ease!

All you can do is to make it harder... but it still always be possibile! Even if you could stop them from downloading the file, you can't stop them from hooking a VCR to their video card and re-recording it. Even if you use some protected-path technology to stop that, you can't stop them from pointing a camcorder at the screen.

Same applies to the ppt presentations... as they can view them... users could take screenshots or do whatever to create their own copy!