# how to hide music href in player?

Tags: html, download, mp3, jplayer

I'm using jplayer on my website but I have only one player on top which plays each mp3 on the page (like deezer). That's why I'm using [demo04](http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-04/), as I want to display the current song playing and I want to add mp3 on the fly (maybe is it possible in an other way?).
I can add music to the player with a simple link, for example :

```
    <a href="http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-05-The-separation.mp3" class="track">The Separation</a>
```

So my problem is coming from the demo which doesn't prevent downloading tracks (right click>save target as) and I need this functionality.

In a few words, is it possible to hide the href or crypt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible.

You can encrypt the name, but an encryption always has a decryption.

Also if you look at search result of Google you will find:

[How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

You can make it hard for users. But you can't stop it.