# how to get Dash segments of .mp4 video file

Tags: html5-video, mpeg-dash, mse

I have mp4 video file,which i need to load on my page,i am using MSE for that,but i don't know how can i get my video in segments with .m4s extensions,with header.m4s as parent segment with all information about my video file stored in it?Please help.

Comment: I can not load that mp4 file directly as i am supposed to make it hard for downloading.So need encrypted url

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if a video is embedded on the website, it can be [downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website).

The only thing you could do is make it difficult for download.

[This](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/streaming/protect/) might be helpful. It says using a [flash video](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/flash/video/) is a good option to make downloading videos a bit difficult. Never used it but you could give it a try.

Comment: Yeah,need to make it difficult for download! flash video it make your page load slow,that is why i ws ingnoring it,bt now ll give a try. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To protect the video, you should probably not try to artificially obfuscate the video loading. MPEG DASH supports encrypted MP4 video and common encryption (CENC), that could be a thing you can look into.

Comment: Well thank you,i did some RnD regarding this,Now i am using  '[AES](http://www.ncc.org.in/download.php?f=NCC2003/F-2.pdf)Algorithm for Video Encryption/Decryption' ,and its working so smooth.