# How to prevent website download, so someone can't download my full website

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, web

How to prevent website download, so someone can't download my full website from IDM or any other software.
is there any possibilities to implement some algorithm or add some security tokens.
what about iframe?
website is on PHP Codeigniter 3.1.4
domain - SSL certificate enabled(https).

Comment: somehow duplicate to  [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Users will be able to download only the views that you populate via php.

CodeIgniter is a MVC (Model-View-Controller) framework for a reason, it encapsulates the business logic from what can be accessed by users.
http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Answer (score 4):

They can't download your full website assuming they can't get access to the php files and or database.

They can only access the output the php generates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Php encoders to prevent your website code.

you can search for different php encoders.

like this one https://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php

Comment: thats ok - but my blog have 80% static data, so they can use same code to display data. how to prevent someone so they can't get my folders and pages inside the folder.