# Disable saving web page with CTRL-S using web components / polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

Is it possible with web components / Polymer to do the following:

- Disable saving web page with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.
- Prevent saving images in any way.
- Prevent copying text in any way.
- Prevent print web page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Comment: Not asking for preventing images and videos! Disable saving web page with CTRL-S using web components / polymer

Comment: The answer to your question is the same as the answer to the linked question.

Comment: You mean it's not possible?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.