# Protect embed video in html or php

Tags: javascript, php, html, video

How to protect video in iframe or video tag?

i have embeded a video. how to hide src url from page view source
to make it non downlodable in system and mobile?

```
 <iframe src="https://www.vimeo.com/embed/xyz"></iframe>
```

is there video tag option available for this? and any other option in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible.  You only have to look at the mass of YouTube downloaders available to realise that videos can be grabbed from even the biggest sites.  The browser needs to receive the information, and if the browsers see's it, so can other people.

Comment: Why don't you try streaming service?