# how to restrict pdf, doc and ppt download in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, restrict, downloading-website-files

I am building a website in Wordress, I am uploading Doc, PPT and Pdf files on wordpres page for viewing purpose for the user but I want to restrict them from getting downloaded. any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are they viewing them through a portal on your site? If they are just viewing them in their browser, then... this is the same as downloading so you cannot have one without the other.

Comment: @ed2 thanks for reply, yes they can see in browser at their end. so there is no way to achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really restrict them, think of it like this, if they can't be downloaded then they also can't be viewed.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this