# How to protect web (frontend) assets from being saved by visitors?

Tags: html, css

Since I'm a newbie in coding, I usually learn by *saving a web page* to understand a web structure, so I can learn & apply it for my own web preference.

But sometimes I found that some websites are not completely downloaded, there are missing assets when or not showing when it's opened locally/offline.

My question is,
Since I'm getting understand about creating a webpage, how can I protect my Arts(webpage) from being saved like I mention in my story above?

Thank you ~

Comment: See [How to prevent downloading images and video files from my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294501/how-to-prevent-downloading-images-and-video-files-from-my-website) Just because the browser doesn't save the complete web page, that doesn't mean that the assets are "protected" in any way. The "save webpage" feature just isn't very good at saving modern web pages that use JS and download assets on the fly.

Comment: I read that kind of information before. But if it is the case, then why there are some downloaded website that cannot load same like the original/online?

Comment: **The "save webpage" feature just isn't very good at saving modern web pages.** It's also not the only way to access the assets.

Comment: So it is the browser it self that make it not completely downloaded?

Comment: You can't always convert a dynamic website into a static website.