# Is there any way to stop copying the text from a webpage?

Tags: html, flash

Is there any way using flash action script to stop copying text from the website. The text will be visible through a swf object and that is locked for selection or copy. it will read the text by HTTP request from a page url in server. Server will send encoded text, which will be decoded by action script.

Is it possible to copy any copy protected text from inside a flash object. Because this text are not visible from the page source. Further as the text is encrypted only the action script can decode it.

Its only some idea but I am not able to make the action script ready to talk to browser and send some http request. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Do not publish it on the web, perhaps?

Comment: If your client is willing to put it on a webpage, then it's not nearly important or valuable enough to bother worrying about.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Copy/Paste in a Web Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020715/disabling-copy-paste-in-a-web-page)

Comment: What do you think is it possible using swf object? I am not sure. Can you please help me out the solve?

Answer (score 3):

You could use an image, but there might still be some software that could extract the text from it, and there's always the problem of getting several well-trained monkeys to copy the text by hand.

So the absolute answer, no, you can't prevent someone from copying your text.

Comment: What do you think about this idea, is it possible?

Comment: What idea? I just told you it's impossible to keep someone from copying you text. If it's copyrighted enough to not be copied, it shouldn't be published on a website.

Comment: I meant to say the flash based text vieweing idea I tried to discuss. But no problem, got your point, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way. If it's shown on client-side, it can be copied.