# How do you disable copy, paste, and print like Amazon's Kindle web e-reader?

Tags: css, html

How does Amazon Kindle's web e-reader (https://read.amazon.com/) disable copy and paste?

Also, how does it make the "printing" of the page render only a blank page?

I reviewed it in the Google Chrome browser, and would like to know what browsers this can be implemented on.

They still allow text selection (for Highlight or Note) so they're not disabling selection, I believe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Copy/Paste in a Web Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020715/disabling-copy-paste-in-a-web-page)

Comment: The question (and answers) aren't specific enough for it to be a duplicate. I'm asking how to select, and highlight text (as in Kindle's e-reader), but disable copy (and thus subsequent paste). Same with print. Thanks for linking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly they are done by JavaScript. They catch the key stroke of `ctrl` + `c` & `ctrl` + `v` then cancel the propagation. And also they disable the right click, by catching the mouse event for right button and stop its propagation.

But this is of **no use** because once the java script is disabled, they are all gone.

The printer printing blank can be done using media queries

```
@media print {

    * { display: none; }

}
```

Comment: Right-clicking doesn't bring up a menu to "copy-paste" apparently?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, WRONG?? Are you kidding me? May be incomplete as I was middle of writing them down but Wrong, give me a break LOL

Comment: Your answer is not a solution. Apologies for using the wrong word to point this out. (or perhaps, 'not completing' what I meant to say, thinking you'd understand)

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, Now i will wait for your answer and see the solution.

Comment: I didn't post because I can't think of one, sorry. :(

Comment: It sounds like there's multiple strategies... disable the context menu, catch the key strokes for ctrl + c (which would make ctrl + v irrelevant? can't paste what you can't catch...)

Comment: How did this get a downvote? Sometimes people on SO drive me crazy! +1 anyways. @ElliotBonneville - how is his answer not a solution? He addressed all three of the guys questions. Key capture for mouse, disable right mouse button and css media for printing. Does he have to code the entire solution into a plugin, then drive over to his house and implement it?

Comment: @mrtsherman: Hehe, this is misleading. Since I downvoted and commented on his answer, he's edited, perhaps more than once. I don't remember seeing the bit about disabling right click when I downvoted.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, Just admit it you hate me :(

Comment: @Starx: Now why on earth would I hate you? You seem like a good guy. =) Some of your answers are a little less helpful imho, that's all.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, I was just kidding :P

Comment: @mrtsherman +1 for suggesting he drive over to the house and implement... It's so rare for a coder to do house-calls...