# Disable copying in a div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there is a way to disable copying text from a div?

I have been to website's where if I try to highlight or copy some of the text, I am unable to. I was wondering if anyone knows how I would achieve this?

```
<div id="description">However, this valorous visitation of a by-gone vexation,
 stands vivified and has vowed to vanquish these venal and virulent vermin
 vanguarding vice and vouchsafing the violently vicious and voracious violation
 of volition. </div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always copy the text looking at the source code of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of that;)

Comment: No, any partly intelligent user can disable JavaScript or view the source to highlight the text they want. There's no point in trying to disable the functionality.

Comment: Can you place the link of that site here?

Comment: Thanks your input. I am aware that, but would still like to find out how to do this.

Comment: This question is definitely "how" not "why shouldn't I?" -  But see this related question once you have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020715/disabling-copy-paste-in-a-web-page

Comment: er, everything but a straight answer...

Comment: If you have a look at that questions you'll find the Javascript you need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using just CSS you can use user-select like so:

```
-moz-user-select: none;  
-webkit-user-select: none;  
-ms-user-select: none;  
-o-user-select: none;  
user-select: none;
```

This works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari, IE10 and up, but not in Opera.

This simply stops a user selecting the text, but that will prevent them copying it. It's nice for text on buttons as well.

In older IE and Opera, you can set it to be unselectable either by using:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("yourElement");
elem.unselectable = "on"; // For IE and Opera
```

in JS, or simply adding the `unselectable` attribute and setting it to on.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/B9yYt/

Comment: +1 for suggesting its use on buttons; imo very few other areas would be appropriate

Comment: Yes, I've only used in on buttons. Being able to copy/paste and hence quote pages is a good thing IMO!

Comment: @RichBradshaw, it works. But if there are other div above and below this this. And I copy from the div above, through this unselectable, and towards the div below, I can still copy the content..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a div above your content like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#content{
    z-index: 0;
    background: grey;
}

#overlay{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Can't touch this</p>
    </div>

    <div id="overlay">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could copy it... just need to play with it a bit.

Comment: Of course. MHZ's goal is completely unrealistic. I'm just giving an answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Your solution fails to solve my problem. Just because you don't know the solution, does not mean my goal is unrealistic. Please look at the best answer to see how realistic my goal is;)

Comment: I do know the solution; which is why I answered the question. Your goal, as I understand it, is to "disable copying text from a div". I'm glad for your question and chosen answer, though. It's a lot more elegant than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not JavaScript - but you can make something 'appear' disabled to selection by using CSS.

```
::-moz-selection { background: #000000; color: #ffffff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background: #000000; color: #ffffff; text-shadow: none; }
```

Keep in mind this isn't cross-browser compatible.

Comment: that does not answer my question, at all.